# Add caseId to Live chat transcript record missed status

Tags: livechattranscript

User initiates a Live Chat session for the existing case but then closes the chat session before an agent accepts the chat, we are finding that a chat transcript is created with status "Missed". I would then like to associate that chat transcript with the CaseId, but I'm not finding a way to do that because I can't find a way to get the chatKey or transcript ID in our custom chat window. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had same requirement- we developed a trigger on Transcript object to lookup and associate it with Case if Status is missed.

Comment: How did you associate the Transcript to the correct Case? The Case is only filled in on the Transcript when the Agent accepts the Transcript.

Comment: When you’re using Omni-Channel routing, the chat transcript is created when the chat’s requested by a visitor; so you can get case Id in that case. If you are not using omni-channel but using pre-chat form then you can find case based on combination of subject+Contact name ...